Range Error and Backspace Handling Issue in Custom OTP Field Flutter Widget
I am working on a custom-made OTP field widget in Flutter and encountering two issues:
Range Error: I am facing a range error when updating the parent controller with the text entered in the OTP fields.
Backspace Handling: When pressing the backspace button, the previous field should be cleared correctly, but it doesn't work as expected.
Here is the relevant code for my custom OTP field widget:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class CustomOtpField extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final int length;
  final double size;
  final double borderRadius;
  final double borderWidth;
  final Color focusedBorderColor;
  final Color unfocusedBorderColor;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final TextStyle textStyle;
  final double fieldSpacing;

  const CustomOtpField({
    required this.controller,
    this.length = 6,
    this.size = 50.0,
    this.borderRadius = 4.0,
    this.borderWidth = 1.0,
    this.focusedBorderColor = Colors.teal,
    this.unfocusedBorderColor = Colors.grey,
    this.backgroundColor = Colors.white,
    this.textStyle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
    this.fieldSpacing = 12.0,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  CustomOtpFieldState createState() => CustomOtpFieldState();
}

class CustomOtpFieldState extends State<CustomOtpField> {
  late List<FocusNode> _focusNodes;
  late List<TextEditingController> _fieldControllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNodes = List.generate(widget.length, (index) => FocusNode());
    _fieldControllers =
        List.generate(widget.length, (index) => TextEditingController());
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.length; i++) {
      _fieldControllers[i].addListener(() => _updateParentController(i));
    }
    widget.controller.addListener(_updateOtp);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (_focusNodes.isNotEmpty) {
        _focusNodes[0].requestFocus();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var node in _focusNodes) {
      node.dispose();
    }
    for (var controller in _fieldControllers) {
      controller.dispose();
    }
    widget.controller.removeListener(_updateOtp);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateParentController(int index) {
    final text = _fieldControllers[index].text;
    final currentText = widget.controller.text;

    if (index >= 0 && index < widget.length) {
      String newText;
      if (text.isNotEmpty) {
        newText = (index > 0 ? currentText.substring(0, index) : '') +
            text +
            (index < widget.length - 1 ? currentText.substring(index + 1) : '');
      } else {
        newText = (index > 0 ? currentText.substring(0, index) : '') +
            (index < widget.length - 1 ? currentText.substring(index + 1) : '');
      }

      widget.controller.text = newText;
      widget.controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: newText.length),
      );
    }
  }

  void _updateOtp() {
    final text = widget.controller.text;
    if (text.length > widget.length) {
      // Ensure the OTP length does not exceed the specified length
      widget.controller.text = text.substring(0, widget.length);
    }
    if (text.length == widget.length) {
      _focusNodes.last.unfocus();
    } else if (text.length < widget.length) {
      _focusNodes[text.length].requestFocus();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.length; i++) {
      if (i < text.length) {
        _fieldControllers[i].text = text[i];
      } else {
        _fieldControllers[i].clear();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: List.generate(widget.length, (index) {
        return Row(
          children: [
            _buildOtpField(index),
            if (index < widget.length - 1) SizedBox(width: widget.fieldSpacing),
          ],
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildOtpField(int index) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.size,
      width: widget.size,
      child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
        controller: _fieldControllers[index],
        onChanged: (value) {
          if (value.length <= 1) {
            if (value.isNotEmpty) {
              if (index < widget.length - 1) {
                _focusNodes[index + 1].requestFocus();
              }
            } else {
              if (index > 0) {
                _focusNodes[index - 1].requestFocus();
              }
            }
            _updateParentController(index);
          }
        },
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        maxLength: 1,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterText: '',
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: widget.backgroundColor,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: _focusNodes[index].hasFocus
                  ? widget.focusedBorderColor
                  : widget.unfocusedBorderColor,
              width: widget.borderWidth,
            ),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: widget.focusedBorderColor,
              width: widget.borderWidth,
            ),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(widget.borderRadius),
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: widget.unfocusedBorderColor,
              width: widget.borderWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        style: widget.textStyle,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Issues:
Range Error: I encounter a range error when updating the parent controller with the text entered in the OTP fields. How can I handle this without causing a range error?
Backspace Handling: When pressing the backspace button, the previous field should be cleared correctly, but it doesn't work as expected. How can I fix this issue?
Additional Context:
I want to make sure that backspace correctly clears the current field and moves the focus to the previous field if needed.
The TextEditingController for each OTP field is managed within the widget.
Thank you for your help!

Which line is causing range error?

Also you've added _updateParentController to both _fieldController's listener and onChanged of the Textfields, you don't need to do it twice.

@Khushal I'm getting range error while substring the currentText, I understand  what the issue was currentText length and index is not matching that was the issue.
I'm using index + 1 for substring that's the reason, if I remove that i can't separate the OTP and I can't manage the focus of text field, and listener was a mistake
